# Debug.WriteLine not working

Tags: vb.net, debugging

In the past, perhaps versions of Visual Studio prior to the 2008 that I am using now, I would do something like this in my VB.NET code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message")
```

..and the output would go to the output window.

Now it doesn't. Something must first apparently be enabled.

If this involves "attaching a debugger", please explain how to do it. It seems to me that it should just work without too much of a fuss.

Here's a video explaining the issue in real time and showing you all my settings:

http://screencast.com/t/YQnPb0mJcs

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All good suggestions.  I noticed that I don't see this tip mentioned, so I'll say it:  **In your app.config file, make sure you don't have a `<clear/>` element** in your trace listeners.

You will effectively be clearing the list of trace listeners, *including the default trace listener used for Debug statements.*

Here's what this would look like in your app.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
          <!-- This next line is the troublemaker.  It looks so innocent -->
          <clear/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

If you want to have a placeholder for trace listeners in your app.config file, you should instead use something like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Oh, good one, this was really bugging me. Turns out this line was the culprit for us: `<remove name="Default" />`

Answer (score 27):

Check to see if the "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" is checked under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.

Alternatively, you can use the `Console.WriteLine()` function as well.

Comment: I did check the option you indicated but, after executing the Debug.writeline, the output still does not go to the Immediate Window. I'd rather not use the Console window.

Comment: Console isn't always available from winforms or wpf programs.

Answer (score 18):

Right-click in the output window, and ensure "Program output" is checked.

Comment: I was pretty sure I had it checked, but checked it up after your answer and it was indeed unchecked :)

Answer (score 16):

Do you definitely have the DEBUG constant defined? Check under project properties -> *Compile* -> *Advanced Compile Options* (there's a checkbox for the DEBUG constant. If it isn't checked, your Debug.XXX statements will not be executed).

Comment: The "Define DEBUG Constant" is checked, but the "Custom Constants" text box is empty. Should a value be in the "Custom Constants" textbox if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: No, custom constants is for custom compilation constants. The TRACE and DEBUG constants are built in

Comment: This was the culprit for me. In Visual Studio 2012 I checked the checkbox under Project > [projectname] Properties... > Build > Define DEBUG constant

Comment: If the code is in a library then also make sure the DEBUG is checked in the library and then recompile library and then source.  It didn't work for me until I checked the DEBUG option in my library.

Answer (score 12):

It should go to the output window if your app is compiled with the Debug configuration rather than the Release configuration.  But instead of `Debug.WriteLine()`, try using `Trace.WriteLine()` (optionally with a `ConsoleTraceListener` attached).

Comment: Under Project Properties, Debug tab, the Configuration dropdown is set to Debug. Still no messages on the Immediate or Output windows.

Comment: Trace while attaching a listener? How to attach a Listener (Console window? Sounds ugly an old)

Comment: You don't need the ConsoleTraceListener.  It's just an option if you want to write the console, and it sounds like you don't.  Just call Trace.WriteLine().

Answer (score 7):

Check your *Immediate Window*. You might have all the output redirected to it.

Comment: Nope. Nothing there. See my answer to Johnny

Answer (score 7):

Some extra ideas to try or check:

- Put a breakpoint before Debug.WriteLine and see what's in [System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners.aspx) collection. You should see [DefaultTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.aspx). If you don't see anything, then no one is listening and that's problem.
- Is it possible that the trace listeners being cleared/modified somewhere such as in config file or in the code?
- Have you installed any package or add-in to Visual Studio? or using a third-party library?
- Can you see debug messages outside of VS? There is a SysInternals application called [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) that monitors and shows debug output in your system. Run that tool and then run your application. You should see your debug message in DebugView. At least you will know that your application is outputting debug messages but VS does not seem to be listening.
- Have you gone through the contents of the output window to see if there is any exception or error being reported. Your debug output is not there but there might be somethings in there that can provide some clues.

Comment: I executed this line:

    Debug.WriteLine("test")

Then executed this in th eImmediate Window:

?  System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Count
1
?  System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners(0).Name
"Default"

The Sys Internals tool showed:

Debug View:
[4812] test 


No output to the Immeditate or Output Window

Answer (score 3):

For me this was the fact that Debug.WriteLine shows in the Immediate window, not the Output. My installation of Visual Studio 2013 by default doesn't even show an option to open the Immediate window, so you have to do the following:

```
Select Tools → Customize 
Commands Tab
View | Other Windows menu bar dropdown
Add Command...
The Immediate option is in the Debug section.
```

Once you have Ok'd that, you can go to menu *View* → *Other Windows* and select the Immediate Window and hey presto all of the debug output can be seen.

Unfortunately for me it also showed about 50 errors that I wasn't aware of in my project... maybe I'll just turn it off again :-)

Answer (score 2):

It happens. I have the similar symptom when I am developing ASP.NET MVC applications on Visual Studio 2010 web developer Express Edition. The execution doesn't break at the breakpoint. There is no output when it executes `System.Diagnostic.Debug.Writeline` (even though it runs with debug start), and there is nothing wrong with `web.config`.

My workaround is:
- Goto project properties--> web
- In the Debugger section, check the the ASP.NET option

Hope this helps someone who comes across this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2013 and MS unit testing. Right clicking on a unit test method and selecting Run Tests any Debug.WriteLine calls would not show up in either the immediate window or the debug output window. Even though the library I was testing and the unit test project itself both had DEBUG conditional checked in the build section of there project properties.

In order for the Debug.WriteLine statements to output anything I needed to run the unit tests by right clicking and selecting Debug Tests. Only then did I get the debug output being written to the debug output window.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem for an ASP.NET application, and I found out that my Web.Config had the following line:

```
<system.web>
    <trace enabled="false"/>
</system.web>
```

Just changing it to true, and I started seeing the `Debug.WriteLine` in `Output` window.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio Express 2010. I fresh installed on a debug machine and none of the suggestions worked. I ended up using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) and logging to a text file as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you press <kbd>F5</kbd> to Start Debugging mode (not <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

> <kbd>F5</kbd> Starting Debugging
>
> **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>** Starting Without Debugging