# Debug.Writeline is Not printing anything

Tags: c#, debugging

VS 2010 Pro, C#, WinForms:
at the very beginning of my method I am saying `Debug.Writeline("entering method blah");` then somewhere inside this method I am putting some breakpoints and run the program. so I see that execution is stopped at those break points, so it is here! but if I search the Output->Debug combobox mode and also Immediate window I cannot find the message I has written for `Debug.Writeline` anywhere.

I also tried that heck box setting in Debug options that says "Redirect all output to Immediate window"....did not help either.

Comment: @msarchet: yes, in Debug

Comment: Is the DEBUG symbol defined? (you can do that for the profile named "Debug")

Comment: @MarcGravell : I am not sure how to check what you mentioned. Do you mean pdb files? yes they are being created.

Comment: go to project-properties in the IDE; there will be a checkbox relating to defining the DEBUG constant; make sure it is checked on debug builds

Comment: @MarcGravell : Perfect. Thanks Sir. it is working now. it was not checked by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug.WriteLine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370449/debug-writeline-not-working)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Discussed already in the comments, but I wasn't sure until discussing it there. However:

- calls to `Debug.Whatever(...)` are typically marked with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`, meaning they require the `DEBUG` symbol to be defined, otherwise those calls ***are not compiled***
- a default project has `DEBUG` and `TRACE` defined for the "Debug" profile, and `TRACE` for the "Release" profile
- however, you can *disable* the `DEBUG` symbol via a checkbox in "project properties"

So; go to project-properties, and ensure the `DEBUG` symbol is defined (or not) as appropriate for your needs (for any-and-all profiles that exist in your project).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you press <kbd>F5</kbd> to Start Debugging mode (**not** <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

> <kbd>F5</kbd> Starting Debugging
>
> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> Starting Without Debugging

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if Debug does not print anything (and you can't breakpoint on it) : you also have to check "TRACE" in project properties.

Answer (score 1):

If there is still no output after all, check the message types that are enabled for the output window:

1. Right-Click inside the content area of the Output-Window.
2. Make sure "Program Output" is selected for example. (It should look like the screenshot)

[image]